# Python Regex: escaping a back-reference

Tags: python, regex, escaping, set, backreference

Here is my situation:

```
re.sub(r'([^\\])', r'\1[\W\1]*', string)
```

It is straight forward that I want to append [\W(itself)] after (itself) for itself being a group of characters (can be special). That is why I need to put it in a set to strip away all special meanings. However, my group can be a SET. I know that nested sets do not work. How do I escape / remove the square brackets to safely put my group in the set?

My other attempt was to use \1(\W|\1)* instead, but I need to escape characters in my group without escaping possible square brackets in the group. How do I do so?

This is a dilemma. I do not know how to solve this problem and which way to go. Please help.

Thank you very much.

EDIT:
I skipped a step. After matching a character but \ (the [^\] part) and replace with the explained expression, I will sometime need to replace it with a set of similar characters. So, 'a' becomes '[a@]', 's' becomes '[s5$]', etc... 
The question was really wrong. But I solved the problem, so if you are still trying to make some sense out of what I wrote earlier, please don't :)

Comment: Can you provide some sample strings as to what needs to be replaced and how?

Comment: I don't understand what you've trying to do. Given, say, `string = 'a'`, your code would return `'a[\\Wa]*'`.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a regex to change an input regex into another regex; is that correct?
Also, is there any limitation that defines the captured group? You now capture any character that is not a backslash. Do you want to capture a single character? Or do you want to replace each character in `string` (that is not a backslash) with "<character>[\W<character>]*"?

Comment: Nobody understands your question. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, I skipped a step in my question. I solved my own problem though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function as the replacement in [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub).  This will allow you to call [`re.escape`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape) on your match before performing the substitution:

```
def escape_repl(match):
    return '{0}[\W{0}]*'.format(re.escape(match.group(1)))

re.sub(r'([^\\])', escape_repl, string)
```

Example:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'([^\\])', escape_repl, '[^$]')
\[[\W\[]*\^[\W\^]*\$[\W\$]*\][\W\]]*
```

I think this is what you are trying to do, but it is a little unclear from your question.  Please provide some sample strings and expected results if this isn't what you're looking for.

Comment: thank you. yes, it was very unclear. but I think I solved I in a different way. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Just had the situation that I wanted to insert a number replaced by a backreference: `re.sub(r"(foo|bar)([ -])\d.\d", r"\1\20.0.0", text)`.
So this answer helped me to use: `re.sub(r"(foo|bar)([ -])\d.\d", lambda x: f"{x.group(1)}{x.group(2)}0.0.0", text)` instead.